# Jump to top when refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was searching for a solution. When the user is on the homepage (one page) and he calls a section in the navigation. It jumps to that section with a smooth scroll. Now I was wondering how I can fix it, when the user is refreshing the page, the page will start at the top of the page, and not at the last section that was visited.

When the user is clicking in the menu "video" it goes to that section with the id `#video`. Because the anchor hash will be in the url, it turns back to that section while refreshing the page. How can I fix it that when refreshing the page it will turn to the top of the page and has no id anymore in the url.

Important is that I have a single page with the same navigation menu, only I have set before the hash symbol `index.html`. When the user then clicks on `video` it should turn to that section. Only when refreshing the page it should go to the top of the page.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/7PKAX/32/

Comment: Why would that be a problem. The end-user was on that section anyway.

Comment: It's not great if I refresh the page and I always go to the last section that I had visited. I have think about it, but I want it that is charged. refresh the page when the user back to the top. @Sigma

Answer (score 0):

you could add `window.location.hash = ''` and `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 500)` just after the `document.ready` function

Comment: It only works for a split second, then it goes to the last section. And It's important that it only works in index.html, so when the user is on the single page like `single.html` and clicks on `video` than it should go to that part on the homepage. @Anubhav

Comment: could you share a link to the live site? the fiddle does not show hash values